# Why won't my SSAS Cube URL Action appear in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, mdx, olap-cube, ssas-2008

I am working with a SSAS 2008 R2 OLAP cube and Excel 2010. I have set up a URL Action in the cube with a target type of Cells and a Target object of All Cells. When I have a hard coded URL in the Action Expression - for example `"http://stackoverflow.com"` everything works fine - that is to say that when I right click on a fact within an Excel 2010 pivot table rendering my cube I can see the Context Menu with additional actions and my URL action is there and it works.

When I try to add any MDX to the action expression - for example        `"http://stackoverflow.com/" + [Measures].[DataValue]` (which should represent the fact I'm right clicking on) - there are no additional actions available.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong, or how to diagnose the actual problem? I'm pretty sure that `[Measures].[DataValue]` should have data in it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your url actually going to the value aggregated value or is it based upon which measure the user clicked? Take a look at this blog and see if it helps: http://timlaqua.com/2009/03/ssas-cube-action-cells-target-type-url-action-type-example/

Comment: It's based on which measure the user clicks - ideally I would like to get back the values of specific dimension attributes that relate to the measure, but at the very least be able to get the primary key of the selected measure. I'm trying to construct a URL that will allow rendering of definitions for the selected measure. The blog you linked to was where I started. Thanks.